# Mount fails in shell script

Tags: bash, mount

I have made a very simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mount -v --bind "\""$1"\"" "\""$2"\""
echo $?
exit 0
```

The script execution fails with error code 1 for:

```
./mymount "/storage/Some folder" "/storage/temp"
```

From command line works fine:

```
mount -v --bind "/storage/Some folder" "/storage/temp"
```

Selinux is disabled.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It might be worth reading some documentation on how quotes work in bash: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting & http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever you have this sort of problem, `set -x` is your friend. Change your script to this and run it again:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
/usr/bin/mount -v --bind "\""$1"\"" "\""$2"\""
echo $?
exit 0
```

That will show you the following output:

```
terdon@tpad ~ $ sudo foo.sh "/storage/Some folder" "/storage/temp"
+ /usr/bin/mount -v --bind '"/storage/Some' 'folder"' '"/storage/temp"'
mount: bad usage
Try 'mount --help' for more information.
+ echo 1
1
+ exit 0
```

As you can see, what is actually being run is:

```
/usr/bin/mount -v --bind '"/storage/Some' 'folder"' '"/storage/temp"'
```

This happens because you have `"\""$1"\""`, so instead of `$1`, what is being passed to `mount` is `"$1"`, *with the quotes included as though they were part of the directory name*. What you want to do is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
/usr/bin/mount -v --bind "$1" "$2"
echo $?
exit 0
```